# How to bridge Swift View in ObjectC for React Native

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I'am new in this Objc and Swift. I need some small example. I dont know what search.

Objective C very complicated for me.

Can anyone give any simple example, how in Objective C import Swift View as react-native module?

```
//this is swift file
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

```
//i need use RCTView and RCTViewManager somehow in ObjectiveC files
```

Please give some example how import SwiftUIView or any other View from Swift to ObjectC
and add export as RCTView

Comment: There are a  number of education Apps that Apple have produced for this very purpose. They are under very obvious names in the App store.
A good start would be to visit swift.org

Comment: I DONT NEED Swift Part of Code. I need ObjectC part of code. And I cant find any useful info about bridging View from Swift to ObjectC

Comment: Did you find some solution or article? I have similar problem

Answer (score 0):

here's a tutorial how to bridge a native iOS component to react-native https://youtu.be/q5M07Q1JFZw but it's for Alert, if you need to create like a completely custom UI element you will probably need to actually learn swift. It would be easier to help you, if you would describe what are you actually trying to accomplish. Because there are rare scenarios when you actually need to program native UI in a native code.

There's also documentation on importing native modules to react-native https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro maybe that can help you.

Comment: not useful. I need export View from swift, not object and methods. I see documentations and already do export modules. But Im stuck on export Views in Swift.
I cant learn all Swift in 3 days.
If I can see some example and try it, this will help learn faster and do what I need.

Comment: bad news - I need mostly ObjC part of code. Shift I can write myself. But ObjC very difficult for fast learning

Comment: can i ask you why do you even need to do that? like whats the end goal?

Comment: I have some native components in swift. I wanna add this components to RN